# Authentication flow for temporary credentials in the browser

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I'm trying to wrap my head around a specific proprietary authentication flow used by one of our customers, and how to implement it in IdentityServer4.

We're developing an SPA with some microservices as backend and do all our authentication/authorization with IdentityServer4. The standard workflow for the SPA is (as expected, I guess) the implicit flow using oidc-client-js (for now).

Now the problem: one of our customers has something like a homebrew SSO solution dating way back. Users basically authenticate at a central portal and get a link to the application with a token attached. This token is valid for a few minutes and contains the temporary user credentials, I need to somehow authenticate at our IdentityServer.

My first attempt was the client credentials flow. Doesn't work, as the client cannot refresh its access token later, once the initial credential token ran out (the client does not and cannot have access to permanent credentials.) My current approach would be to kind of "hijack" the implicit flow, by authenticating with the given temporary credentials and from there on out use the normal refresh cycle without further need for any credentials.

Is this a valid approach or am I completely on the wrong track? If it's valid: how do I get IdentityServer4 to do my bidding? I cannot use IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, because that would require the client credentials flow (I think?). Is an IExtensionGrantValidator the way to go? (If so: any ideas, how to convince oidc-client-js to use a custom grant?)

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Markus